# Appending a sibling element after a child element in xml using Element Tree

Tags: python, xml, elementtree

I have created a element using Elementtree. I want to append this element after a username.
I found username I wanted but not able to add element after that username.

My code:

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

root = ET.parse("sample.xml")

feature_list = ET.Element('FeatureList')

for f in range(0,5):
    ele = ET.SubElement(feature_list, 'FeatureDetail')
    sub_ele = ET.SubElement(ele, 'FeatureId')
    sub_ele.text = str(f)

for UserName in root.findall('.//UserName'):
    if(UserName.text == 'john@abc.com'):
        Sibling= Sibling.UserName
        Sibling.append(feature_list)
```

There is no command sibling in Elementtree. How to add element after username that I found. Thanks in advance. I want solution in Element tree only not in lxml.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't have sibling method, that is correct in `lxml`. But there are options like `addnext` and `addprevious` which you can use.

Try this:

```
for UserName in root.findall('.//UserName'):
    if(UserName.text == 'john@abc.com'):
        UserName.addnext(feature_list )
```

Comment: Got error: `AttributeError: 'xml.etree.ElementTree.Element' object has no attribute 'addnext'` Let me know solution in Element tree not lxml

Comment: lxml has addnext/addprevious. These methods are not available in ElementTree.

Comment: @mzjn Is there any solution in ELement tree? How to ahieve this using Elemnt tree?

Comment: I achieved my requirement using beautifulsoup